# executing a method in case both the try catch fail

Tags: c#

I have some code that looks like this:

```
string TheString = string.Empty;

try
{
  TheString = SomeDangerousMethod();
}
catch
{
  TheString = SomeSaferMethod();
}

return TheString;
```

It turns out that `SomeSaferMethod` is not so safe and can also fail in some edge case. For this reason, I created a method called `SuperSafeMethod` that I want to call in case the `SomeSaferMethod` also fails in the catch statement.

How can I change my try catch so that there's a third level of execution that triggers if both `SomeDangerousMethod` and `SomeSaferMethod` fail?

Comment: If you expect the method to fail, consider not using exceptions at all in this case. Return `null` instead. Then call the next safer method if the previous returned `null`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Perhaps nested `try/catch` can be used:

```
try
{
    TheString = SomeDangerousMethod();
}
catch
{
  try
  {
      TheString = SomeSaferMethod();
  }
  catch
  {
      TheString = SuperSaferMethod();
  }
}

return TheString;
```

Comment: Ah cool, I didn't know you could nest; thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 6):

You could do the following to avoid nesting. This allows you to use as many methods as you want, in a cleaner fashion.

```
Func<string>[] methods = { SomeDangerousMethod, SomeSaferMethod, SuperSafeMethod };

foreach(var method in methods)
{
   try
   {
       TheString = method();
       break;
   }
   catch { }
} 

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(TheString))
    throw new TooMuchUnsafetyException();
```